# Cakephp, dynamically write variables into css file upon load of view?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, css, cakephp

I'm working out a process to save actions that occur from jquery in my view in cakephp.. I figure an easy way to load the saved values, such as the width and height for a DIV, would be to have cakephp echo a variable as their width / height in the css file, much the same way it would do this in the view file.. I guess I'm not sure exactly where to look for info on this, if its in the cakephp cookbook I guess I'm missing it as I don't see how to do it in there.. any advice is appreciated.

Comment: do you want to be able to save those changes to disk or just keep them for the duration of the page view?

Comment: I've already got the saving of the data part figured out.. my jquery calls my cakephp controller and saves the DIV info to a database, so the issue for me is just how I can then set these changes into the css file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is actually pretty easy (and powerful), and can be done without the aid of CakePHP.

First, make a new file in your webroot called `css.php`.  At the top of that file put the following:

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/css"); ?>
```

Now, link to this file in the head of your layout, just as you would a normal CSS file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/css.php" type="text/css" />
```

And there you have it, a dynamic CSS file.  You can pass information to it like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/path/css.php?c=red&fw=700" type="text/css" />
```

**CLARIFICATION:** To access the variables mentioned above, you would use the `$_GET` variable in the CSS file.  Take a look at the link tag above.  To access those variables in the css file, you would do something like this:

```
.class {color:<?php echo $_GET['c']; ?>;font-weight:<?php echo $_GET['fw']; ?>;}
```

**UPDATE:**  After viewing the link you posted about the CakePHP HTML Helper, I realized that there is a better way to do this if you intend to pass a lot of variables to the css file.

Create a new model and controller called DynamicStyle and DynamicStylesController (or something similar).  Then, make a new layout file called css.ctp that all of this controller's views will use.  Declare the content-type header statement in that layout file.

The last step would be to link to a method in that controller from the head of your standard layout header.

Now you could make a database table of css rules and use those with the HTML helper in the css view.

Comment: I'm a bit confused on this.. so how would I then pass a variable to the css file? Would I have to declare it in the css.php file first?

Answer (score 2):

I just realized CakePHP has something for this as well:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1440/style

So this may come in handy for anyone who comes across this in the future

Comment: This link is not available anymore.